# Redirecting to other page doesn't work, because image makes header info

Tags: php, html, database, image, header

I'm trying to upload an image to my database and retreive it later for use.

I've got this all working but when I'm on the page where it shows the image I can't use : `header("location: ../Home/Home.php");` anymore. It says :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\wamp\www\Helpdesk
>   SALTO\Helpdesk\Melding\VMelding.php:66) in C:\wamp\www\Helpdesk
>   SALTO\Helpdesk\Melding\VMelding.php on line 114

It is being send by my image an echo of : `img height ="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row2["image"].'`

`$row2["image"]` : contains largeblob information of the image in my database.

- Is there another way to redirect to another page ?

  If not:
- is there a way for me to still show the image without it using header information ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can redirect by JS.

Something like this: `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: Call to undefined function replace() in C:\wamp\www\Helpdesk SALTO\Helpdesk\Melding\VMelding.php  and Notice: Use of undefined constant location - assumed 'location' in C:\wamp\www\Helpdesk SALTO\Helpdesk\Melding\VMelding.php same goes for window

Comment: Never mind I got it. It figured out a little late that it was HTML and not PHP.

Comment: Well is JS, not html ^^

Comment: Haha, seems a was a little sleepy at the time. Thanks for the help!